# What is the correct pattern for invoking CMSensorRecorder accelerometer recording to avoid a deadlock warning?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

Working with CoreMotion, invoking CMSensorRecorder.recordAccelerometer(forDuration: recordTime) on main results in a console warning:

> [Motion] Warning - invoking recordDataType:forDuration: on main may lead to deadlock.

Apple Docs don't address this issue or provide a recommended pattern for invocation.

What is the 'right' way to invoke recording to avoid this (or otherwise what is this warning trying to achieve - i.e. what is the possible source of deadlock?)